# specify that a variable type can be any of two values

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I specify in stypescript that a variable can by of type `Car` or `Bar` ?

```
class Car {
  wheels: number;
}

class Bar {
  drinks: number;
}

let foo: Car | Bar;
// now foo has to have the fields of Car AND Bar.
// I would like foo to be of type Car, OR Bar
// foo = { wheels: 4} should not raise an error
// foo = { drinks: 4} should not raise an error
```

Comment: You could do `let foo: Car & Bar;` to say `foo` has fields of both types, but then won't be able to assign a `Car` or `Bar` to `foo`, you would have to assign something with fields of both types. What you have works just fine for assignments but you have to use type guards around any access that requires it to be one or the other.

Comment: The way you did it. Error will not be raised in both cases. `foo` has to have the fields of Car **OR** Bar

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your usage in `instanceof`:

```
class Car {
  wheels: number;
}

class Bar {
  drinks: number;
}

let foo: Car | Bar;

if (foo instanceof Car) {
  foo.wheels;
}

if (foo instanceof Bar) {
  foo.drinks;
}
```

Typescript needs to know, otherwise it won't prevent you from attempting to access `wheels` on a `Bar` object, and that makes it a great deal less useful.

As per your example, assignment: `foo = { wheels: 4}` does not seem to complain in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20wheels%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20drinks%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%3A%20Car%20%7C%20Bar%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo%20%3D%20%7B%20wheels%3A%204%20%7D%3B).